# Pandas: Read excel file for specific columns, remove empty rows, create CSV

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, csv

I am trying to read a folder of .xlsm files, take columns A:J, remove any empty rows, and then combine each excel file into a single CSV. The code below seems to work when I use just one specific excel file but has an error when I loop. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

# defines the folder to pull from and to save into
source = r"C:\Users\bwendt\QAR" 

#defines list of files as dir and changes directory to source
os.chdir(source) 
files = glob.glob(source + "/*.xlsm")
MultiRents = []

#loops through list of file paths, reads the file, removes blank cells, and adds to data frame
for f in files:
   data = pd.read_excel(f,"Page2",usecols = "A:J")
   #data.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=True)
   MultiRents.append(data)

#create pandas DF
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(MultiRents)

#Exports dataframe to a csv file
export_csv = df.to_csv("Multifamily_Rents.csv")
```

> Traceback:  Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/bwendt/.spyder-py3/Print_rents.py', wdir='C:/Users/bwendt/.spyder-py3')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/bwendt/.spyder-py3/Print_rents.py", line 21, in
>   
>       data = pd.read_excel(f,"Page2",usecols = "A:J")
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py",
>   line 188, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py",
>   line 188, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py",
>   line 350, in read_excel
>       io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py",
>   line 653, in **init**
>       self._reader = self._enginesengine
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py",
>   line 424, in **init**
>       self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py",
>   line 157, in open_workbook
>       ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py",
>   line 92, in open_workbook_xls
>       biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py",
>   line 1278, in getbof
>       bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bwendt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py",
>   line 1272, in bof_error
>       raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
>
> XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record;
>   found b'\x0eWendt, '

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: just added, just getting used to this platform. Apologies and appreciate the help.

Comment: For python 3.7, and for .xlsx format, it gives me ImportError: Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support
 on macOS with the file made using numbers. Same for .xls format.

Comment: how is your excel file ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by how is it, it is not corrupt, in the proper location. I can run this code when I use the exact file name but not loop through multiple files.

Comment: when you just open the file xlsm (without python) ...you see a pop with "The file format and extension of don't match."?

Comment: Nope, the excel file is fine. No error or warning message.

Comment: So after all of my research, apparently pandas has issues with xlsm files.